# Camel HTTP Component seems to freeze

Tags: java, apache-camel

Can anyone explain why the following route simply blocks?

```
from("restlet:http://127.0.0.1:8081/nextbus/test")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                .to("http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=charm-city")
                .process(new Processor() {

                    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                        // Do more stuff.
                    }
                });
```

If I remove the invocation to call the next bus web service then everything is fine.

Or if I create a route that is from the web service, also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this after some painful debugging.

Looks like the restlet headers interfere with the http headers. The following works...

```
<route>
        <from uri="restlet:http://0.0.0.0:8081/nextbus/{agency}/{command}" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>GET</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <removeHeader headerName="CamelHttpUri" />
        <recipientList>
            <simple>http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=${header.command}&amp;a=${header.agency}</simple>
        </recipientList>            
</route>
```